# Does Deezer APIs track method return unreliable results?

Tags: api, deezer

Here are some example (setting italy as country):

http://api.deezer.com/2.0/track/2566127 says the track is not readable, but I can play it both from deezer.com and from an API app, the same for http://api.deezer.com/2.0/track/7960580

http://api.deezer.com/2.0/track/3259613 says the track is not readable, it is actually not existent (and usually for not existent track the API return error)

Some other times a track (which used to exist) results as not existent (e.g. http://api.deezer.com/2.0/track/17737916 Beatles - Till There Was You) both from API and deezer.com player (http://www.deezer.com/it/track/17737916) BUT if I search the song using the tile from deezer.com I can see that the track is available with a new id (APIs don't give me the "alternative" id, though).

Am I doing something wrong or the APIs responses are sometime just nor reliable?

Answer (score 0):

Tracks in the Deezer API have now an "alternative" field as well as "available_countries" to deal with those country availability issues. You can check it in the [API Explorer](http://developers.deezer.com/api/explorer?url=track/2566127).

This is however not working for deprecated track ids, because queries on unexisting tracks will just result in a DataException. You could use ISRC codes to work around that, that we now provide as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: Having the available_countries field is actually an awesome news, but the problem above remains: why http://api.deezer.com/2.0/track/2566127 says the track is not readable, but I can play it both from deezer.com and from an API app?

I knew about the "alternative" field but sometime (as in the beatles example I did) it doesn't work

Comment: The readable attribute depends on your GEOIP or from the country associated with the token if one is given. If you get different results, that's probably because the request isn't exactly the same (different token or different GEOIP).

Comment: I get the "not readable" result calling the API directly from the browser (italy), I use deezer from the same browser and for the Deezer app I've tried with my premium user token (italian), so how can the result be different?

Comment: Please send me your user ID, we'll know wether it's a bug or a feature.

Comment: You mean sending via email? Which address?

Comment: I've just sent it! Thanks